# Matlab: How to merge redundant numbers

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a vector `A = [1 1 2 1 3 3 3 ...]` and I want to represent A as `B = [1 2 1 3..]`, that is the repeating numbers are merged and the length(B) is less than length(A). Can somebody please show the code how to do it? Thank you

Comment: Sorry, was not aware that this problem has already been solved. Than you for the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [diff](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html):

```
A(logical([1 diff(A)]))
```